# Exception in logs on starting Hybris with JRebel

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud, jrebel

> Exception in thread "rebel-messaging-executor-44"
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> sun.security.ssl.InputRecord._jr$ig$handshakeHash(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lsun/security/ssl/HandshakeHash;

System Details:

- Java 11.0.12
- Hybris 2005.0
- jrebel-2021.4.1

I have downloaded the JRebel zip file then unizipped it. Also, installed the JRebel IntelliJ plugin.

local.propeties

```
tomcat.javaoptions=-Xverify:none -javaagent:"C:\\Users\\CHISHTM\\Downloads\\jrebel-2021.4.1-nosetup\\jrebel\\jrebel.jar=de.hybris.tomcat.HybrisWebappClassLoader60" -agentpath:C:\\Users\\CHISHTM\\Downloads\\jrebel-2021.4.1-nosetup\\jrebel\\lib\\jrebel64.dll
```

Comment: please do ant build or restart the hybris instance

Comment: @RaushanKumar: no luck

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: Please specify your java version, hybris version, jrebel version. Have you configured it correctly ? https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/advanced/hybris.html https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2105/en-US/8be5ab06866910149c83e0bd4a187fd8.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new JRebel Agent no longer works using -javaagent. This change affects users previously running with the Legacy Agent from a command line (as well as on a remote machine or container)
from here:
https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/misc/jrebel7-agent-upgrade-cli.html

Remove -javaagent argument from javaoptions or downgrade to an older JRebel version.
Its working well just with -agentpath argument.
Tested on newer Hybris + latest Java 11 + latest JRebel